# Programming microcontroller to store images and displaying them as a dia-show with an dvi/hdmi output in several resolutions?

Tags: microcontroller, photos

I would like to solder a microcontroller, control buttons and an DVI/HDMI output and program this in a way, that I can store images on it and let them display as a dia-show via the outputs.

It doesn't have to have a lot of storage capacity, 128Mb would be enough.
but I don't know how to start, because I haven't done anything like this before.

My aim is to present some important images to friends by just taking this hardware, connecting it to a TV screen and showing these photos. If should be able to switch the photos manually (using a button) or automatically in a dia-show.

It should support several TV resolutions and it should be connectable to my PC (USB prefered), so that I can upload and delete photos.

So where to start and how to do that?

Thank you in advance, Andreas

Comment: Hrm... Perhaps cleaning up your post by separating words and using correct punctuation along with well thought out sentences would elicit better response.

Comment: This is not programming in the sense of this site. You need help with the entire end-to-end project, and there are better places to look for it.

Comment: This is a much larger project than you realize. Buy an off-the-shelf unit that has this capability, here's an example: http://www.wdc.com/en/products/index.asp?cat=30

Comment: Hi, thank you for allof these nice answers.
I know, that this will be difficult, because it's DIY in hard- AND software.
and the reason for not wanting to use an off-the-shelf thingy is, that they are big and I don't need all ofit's functions.

the biggest hardware parts will be the controller and the jacks, but it is still about the size of an old usb stick. so I could hang it onto my key ring :)

Comment: Again, you underestimate the size of the project by at least an order of magnitude. To make it fit in the size of a USB stick it will need to be a single-chip controller dedicated specifically to this function. No such chip exists.

Comment: You should also at least give some information on what you've done so far. Did you ever do anything similar before? Do you have any programming experience?

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is just to show some photos, there are assuredly simpler and more cost effective ways to do so; devices exist which do more or less exactly what you are proposing.

If your aim is to learn about microcontrollers and this is a project your are taking up to further that, I would recommend looking into the Arduino: http://www.arduino.cc/ or a similar kit based micro, and growing your project from that.

Answer (score 1):

Microcontroller + low level language will be a huge pain to work with, particularly if you wish to handle various file formats and screen resolutions. Get a full-blown computer with an OS instead - something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/104

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is purely to be able to display photos then I would recommend using a digital camera with video out capabilities.

If your aim is to learn about electronics and microcontrollers I would start with a good [book](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9301) and an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) board. Note that writing microcontroller code to handle file systems, image formats and video output is non-trivial. Simpler projects may be a better starting point as they are more accessible resulting in quicker progress, less frustration and more motivation!

Comment: Yikes!! Must be a 'Mike' thing!

Answer (score 1):

The engineering field is a interesting field. You can start with the web site "www.microchip.com". You will need a high end device consider the PIC32MX795L512, there is a nice starter kit for it, "Ethernet Starter Kit" http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2615&dDocName=en545713. This kit has the on board debugger & programmer to do all the hard work.

You get sample projects with the package, you can program using ansi c programming.
IDE : MPLAB which is free, and the C32 compiler has a student/lite version.

Arduino also has a board with the same device.
I personally like "www.techtoys.com.hk", they have device compatible with Microchip boards like techtoys.com.hk/PIC_boards/PIC32STK%20SSD1963%20EVK/PIC32STK%20SSD1963%20EVK%20R1A.htm, or this techtoys.com.hk/PIC_boards/PIC2432EVK-RD4/PIC2432%20EVK%20RD4.htm where this board you will need a debugger/programmer like the low cost PIC Kit 3 "microchip.com/pickit3".

The trouble is you need to write the HDMI video library yourself, there are some VGA libraries available but they are only black and white and very hard to get color with these analog images. The rest of the libraries are already there, USB MSD(flash drive), SD Card, pictures (jpg) etc.
microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en547784

Feel free to contact me if you need some help, I might be able to help with the HDMI library.

It's a lot of fun to play with these toys.

Regards
Lucas
B-Eng Digital Engineering.
imlucanio@yahoo.com (no spamming)
Remember to add the http and www to the web links.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an iPod.  That is a dead simple thing to work with and it does everything you want.  Otherwise, very complicated.  I'd suggest the BeagleBoard and embedded Linux.  Yes, it warrants that level of complexity.

The options for small microcontrollers just aren't there.  The Arduino is very popular and yes, you can interface an SD card to it.  That'd be your storage.  Yes, you can put a digital potentiometer on it, that can be your interface.  I've seen some video overlays that do simple text, but never any JPEG display (too much processing required).  And certainly no 24 bit color (so that the output would actually look good) - that would take WAY too many pins to do correctly (and the Arduino doesn't have a D/A converter!  You'd have to rig something up that would suck).  And even then, all of the options for TV out weren't HDMI, but RCA (the old red/white/yellow cables).

So in short, no.  Get a computer.  That's what can do the job.